# Decrypt pcap RC4 encryption with pycrypto

Tags: python, encryption, pycrypto, tshark, rc4-cipher

Part of a training exercise I'm doing I need to **decrypt data transmitted and saved in a pcap**.

I know the encryption is **RC4** and I have the key which I know is correct

I wrote a really basic python script using pycrypto which I thought would do it but for some reason the output is still gibberish

Got the data from the pcap file by running this:

```
tshark -nr file.pcapng -q -z follow,tcp,ascii,5 > output
```

The script I wrote using pycrypto:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import ARC4

key = ARC4.new('my_key')
content = open('output','r')
text = content.read()
msg = key.decrypt(text)
print(msg)
```

Output, although different, does not seem to correctly decrypt the TCP stream. Any suggestions? Have I done anything wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [SO tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as this [question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Without the file, this is not a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please [add a link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58405553/edit) to one on Cloudshark, Google Drive, etc.

Comment: tshark can't read or write an encrypted capture file, so I don't understand what you're doing.

Comment: The pcap isn't encrypted. The data in the tcp stream is. I'm using tshark to extract the tcp stream and place it in a file and then running the pycrypto script to decrypt the data from that file

Comment: tshark doesn't sound very appropriate in this case. Writing down the output to ascii sounds hazardous to me. You could try reading the pcap with Scapy instead, with which you can extract the payload, turn it to bytes then call your decryption function using PyCrypto.

Comment: Thanks @Cukic0d
Sadly I don't have scapy on this machine and the whole training is designed to get me to use tshark and pycrypto in this section so I can't install it

Comment: okay. Maybe try exporting the packets in a simpler format to read, like json (I know tshark supports that), or actually anything else than ascii (except if it's base64 encoded ? I'm not sure what your tshark command actually outputs..) That might help. Note you should expand your answer with for instance all those details (what is in the file?), otherwise it's too hard for people to guess.